# How to sum just the decimal values from a string in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with a system that sells products using Kiosks, these Kiosks receives both bills and coins. The payments made in the Kiosks are registered in the database like this:

```
Product cost $5
```

Customer inserts two bills of $2 and the rest in coins like 1 coin of 0.50, 2 coins of 0.20 and 1 coin of 0.10.

In the database it show this in a nvarchar value:

```
(2,2,0.50,0.20,0.20,0.10)
```

It is a sum of all the bills and coins inserted in the Kiosk in just one field.

I need to get and sum only the coins from this field. How do I do that in SQL Server?

I know that it would be easier if the table divides the bills from coins but I have control over how these records are created.

The table definition is:

```
KioskID INT 
Payments nvarchar(250)
PaymentCommited INT
```

In the example I gave above I want to sum all the coins and the expected value for field Payments would it be 1.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Please provide proper table definitions, sample data and expected result.

Comment: `In the database it show this in a nvarchar value (2,2,0.50,0.20,0.20,0.10). It is a sum of all the bills and coins inserted in the Kiosk in just one field.` Why? Why not store each insertion on its own row? Also how do you know when `1` is a one dollar coin vs. a one dollar bill?

Comment: _it show this in a nvarchar value_ That is the most important problem to be addressed NOW. Almost certainly - from an auditing point of view at least - you will need to capture the quantity of each type of coin (and likely the same for bill denominations). Does your currency not have a coin that is also the same value as the lowest bill denomination? Most do.

Comment: This is a profoundly broken way to save the data to the database :(

Comment: @SMor In the US, the only overlap is for $1 coins and bills, but the coins are much rarer and many kiosks do not accept them. Therefore just knowing the amount of the item really is enough to know if it's a coin or a bill.

Comment: guys, I don't have control of how these data are being saved in the database, the Kiosk developers send the data to the database. My job is to build a report of it using these data. I know it is very broken but as I said I don't have control of this :( 

anyway thanks for the comments.

Comment: In the UK, there is no overlap for coins and notes. The largest coin is £2 and the smallest note is £5. The same is true for Euros, where it's again €2 and €5 respectively. So, like Joel mentioned, most of the time, you can tell what the tender type was based on its value.

Comment: In Canada, however, $1 and $2 coins are the norm, but $1 and $2 bills still float around. Even in the US there are $2 bills. Uncommonly used, like $1 coins, but that is different from not existing. We have no idea what country the OP is in, but they mention 50-cent piece, which is equally uncommon, and 20-cent piece, which hasn't existed in the US in centuries maybe, so...

Answer (score 3):

Issues with your data aside, at a guess you want to sum all the decimal values in the provided sample string.

You could use `string_split` to get each value as a row and then sum:

```
declare @dodgydata varchar(100)='2,2,0.50,0.20,0.20,0.10'

select Sum(Try_Convert(decimal(5,2),value)) as CoinTotal
from (select @dodgydata dd)d
cross apply String_Split(dd,',')
where value like '%.%';
```

Note of course this can only work if the coin denominations don't co-exist with note denominations, otherwise with data of `'1,1'` is that two notes or two coins or one of each?

Comment: This is basically right. But since he only wants the coins, also add a `CASE` expression inside the `SUM()` to filter for values less than 1, and treat anything else as 0.

Comment: That's the point of the `where` criteria - I don't think there would be decimal fraction value notes. Perhaps `'0.%'` but I think it's fine.